# Функция которая будет возвращать список, в который записаны последовательно ключи и значения

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

> Написать функцию `flatten_dict(d)`, принимающую на вход словарь d и
>   возвращающую список, в который записаны последовательно ключи и
>   значения словаря d (порядок следования ключей не важен, но после
>   каждого ключа должно идти значение, которое ему соответствует).
>   Например, `flatten_dict({'Alice':1, 'Bob':2})` может вернуть список
>   `['Alice', 1, 'Bob', 2]` или список `['Bob', 2, 'Alice', 1]`.

Я написал следующий код:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    new_dict = []
    keyz = [i for i in d.keys()]
    valuez = [i for i in d.values()]
    i = 0
    while len(new_dict) != len(keyz) + len(valuez):
       new_dict.append(keyz[i])
       new_dict.append(valuez[i])
       i += 1
    return new_dict
```

Он работает, но уверен, можно было бы сделать лаконичнее.

Comment: Дело в том, что я учу Python для анализа данных, по материалам из "http://math-info.hse.ru". Там ответов нет, только задачи и перепроверить себя - нет возможности.

Comment: Если Вы учите питон, то Вам не надо учить анализ данных. Вам нужен именно python. Выучите синтаксис https://pythontutor.ru/

Comment: Спорить прекращаем. [Инспекция кода у нас разрешена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/15479).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вообще в одну строку:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    return [x for y in d.items() for x in y]
```

Результат:

```
['Alice', 1, 'Bob', 2]
```

Comment: если вас не затруднит, поправьте меня пожалуйста: [x for y in d.items() for x in y] расшифровывается как - каждый x и y в d.items(), для каждого x и y в новом списке. Я всё верно понял?

Comment: Фактически это прямо разворачивается в два вложенных цикла обычного кода Питона: `for y in d.items():` `for x in y:` `result.append(x)`

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    new_dict = []
    for k, v in d.items():
       new_dict.append(k)
       new_dict.append(v)
    return new_dict
```